# Secondary sort on ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, sorting, secondary-sort

i am trying to sort my Arrayadapter with it's sort-Method

```
@Override
public void sort(@NonNull Comparator<? super Task> comparator) {
    super.sort(comparator);
}
```

two times.

I'm using the two Comparators

```
private static final Comparator TASKCOMPARATOR_TITLE = new Comparator<Task>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Task a, Task b) {
        return a.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(b.getTitle());
    }
};

private static final Comparator TASKHOLDERCOMPARATOR_DUEDATE = new Comparator<ViewHolder>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ViewHolder a, ViewHolder b) {
        return a.getTask().getDueTime().compareTo(b.getTask().getDueTime());
    }
};
```

like this

```
taskAdapter.sort(Util.getTASKCOMPARATOR_TITLE());
taskAdapter.sort(Util.getTASKCOMPARATOR_DUEDATE());
```

hoping to secondary sort the ArrayAdapter by the title and then by the Date. The sort-Method of the ArrayAdapter is internally using

```
public void sort(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        if (mOriginalValues != null) {
            Collections.sort(mOriginalValues, comparator);
        } else {
            Collections.sort(mObjects, comparator);
        }
    }
    if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I've read, that Collections.sort() is using a stable algorithm and therefore i'm wondering why the List of my ArrayAdapter is just being sorted by the last comparator i call.

Can anyone tell me where i made a mistake and why the first sort()-call is being ignored by the second one?

**EDIT**

```
private static final Comparator TASKCOMPARATOR = new Comparator<Task>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Task a, Task b) {
        int timeCompareResult = a.getDueTime().compareTo(b.getDueTime());
        if (timeCompareResult == 0) {
            return a.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(b.getTitle());
        } else {
            return timeCompareResult;
        }
    }
};
```

This works. I don't know if it's the only/best way.

Comment: Just use one comparator and sort by two parameters there. If titles are same then sort by date. It's elementary. Also you can abstract it and write universal comparator that accepts two inner comparators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Шах stated, use one comparator.
Comparator returns 0 on equals.
First compare on Title, if they are equal you go for the comparison on Time.
I haven't ran the code, but it should be something like this:

```
private static final Comparator TASKHOLDERCOMPARATOR_DUEDATE = new Comparator<ViewHolder>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ViewHolder a, ViewHolder b) {
        int comparison = a.getTask().getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(b.getTask().getTitle());

        if(comparison == 0){
            comparison = a.getTask().getDueTime().compareTo(b.getTask().getDueTime());
        }
        return comparison;
    }
};
```